# jpql order by size error

Tags: exception, jpql

Can anyone explain why this throws a JPQL exception?

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select object(o) from SiteMember as o order by size(o.memberThread) desc");

memberThread refer a list.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely because you use a JPA implementation (also database vendor can matter) which does not have vendor extension for such a query. According JPA 2.0 following types of value can be with in `ORDER BY`:

```
 1.A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to an orderable state field of an 
   entity or embeddable class abstract schema type designated in the SELECT clause 
   by one of the following:  
 • a general_identification_variable  
 • a single_valued_object_path_expression  

 2.A state_field_path_expression that evaluates to the same state field of the same 
  entity or embeddable abstract schema type as a state_field_path_expression in the
  SELECT clause

3.A result_variable that refers to an orderable item in the SELECT clause for which 
 the same result_variable has been specified. This may be the result of an
 aggregate_expression, a  scalar_expression, or a state_field_path_expression in the 
 SELECT clause.
```

Your query works for example with EclipseLink(2.3.2) and MySQL.

Comment: i use Toplink and this code works fine "select object(o) from MemberThread as o where size(o.replys) = '0' order by o.id desc".any solution please?

Comment: That one is valid JPQL query. Problem in question is ORDER BY combined with illegal value. Most likely just sorting result of query is fine, at least no portability problems. If that is not option, you can try following (not guaranteed to work): add 'size(o.memberThread) as ord' to SELECT, order by ord, and group by fields in SiteMember. Then it gets of course ugly, because result contains also attribute that was needed only for ORDER BY.

Comment: You are welcome, unfortunately is it possible that it will not solve your problem (I do not have TopLink to test with).